# Oracle 12C - %TYPE in JSON_TABLE column doesn't work

Tags: sql, json, oracle, sql-insert, oracle12c

I'm trying to save a JSON array as database rows:

```sql
   INSERT INTO log (
      "uuid",
      "date",
      "msg",
      "level"
   )
      WITH t ( log ) AS (
         SELECT
            JSON_QUERY('[{"uuid": "20000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000", "date": "2021-10-17", "msg":"aaaa", "level": "debug" },
                     {"uuid": "20000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000", "date": "2021-10-17", "msg":"bbbb", "level": "debug" }]'
            , '$')
         FROM
            dual
      )
      SELECT
         "uuid",
         "date",
         "msg",
         "level"
      FROM
         t
         CROSS JOIN
            JSON_TABLE ( log, '$'
               COLUMNS (
                  NESTED PATH '$[*]'
                     COLUMNS (
                        "uuid" VARCHAR2 ( 36 ) PATH '$.uuid',
                        "date" DATE PATH '$.date',
                        "msg" VARCHAR2 ( 1024 ) PATH '$.msg',
                        "level" VARCHAR2 ( 5 ) PATH '$.level'
                     )
               )
            )
```

When I try to use the `%type`:

```sql
                  NESTED PATH '$[*]'
                     COLUMNS (
                        "uuid" VARCHAR2 ( 36 ) PATH '$.uuid',
                        "date" my_table.date%type PATH '$.date',
                        "msg" VARCHAR2 ( 1024 ) PATH '$.msg',
                        "level" VARCHAR2 ( 5 ) PATH '$.level'
                     )
```

I get an error:

```
SQL Error: ORA-40484: invalid data type for JSON_TABLE column
40484. 00000 -  "invalid data type for JSON_TABLE column"
*Cause:    A column in the provided JSON_TABLE had an unsupported data type.
*Action:   Provide a supported data type.
```

Even though the type in the column is also `date`.

Also the type `char(36)` doesn't work, so I have to use `VARCHAR2(36)`.

Is it possible to use `%type` in this case?

Comment: Please, check [the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/JSON_VALUE.html#GUID-C7F19D36-1E75-4CB2-AE67-ADFBAD23CBC2). It lists all the possible values for type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`JSON_TABLE` documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/JSON_TABLE.html#GUID-3C8E63B5-0B94-4E86-A2D3-3D4831B67C62) gives the syntax for the JSON query column clause:

> [image: Syntax diagram for JSON_TABLE column clause]

Following the link to the [`JSON_value_return_type` documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/JSON_VALUE.html#GUID-C7F19D36-1E75-4CB2-AE67-ADFBAD23CBC2) tells you the allowable data types:

> [image: Syntax diagram for JSON data type]

Given this, no, you cannot use `%TYPE` or `CHAR` as the `JSON_TABLE` syntax does not allow it.